# How can i fetch last message from conversations

Tags: mysql

I have conversation database structure like this ..

'message_id' , 'message' , 'sender_id' , 'recipent_id' as sketch . how can I fetch last message.

Comment: How can we know? There is no timestamp for each message?

Comment: i want it order by message_id

Comment: [{ "message_id" : 3 , "sender_id" : 1 , "recipent_id" : 2 , "message" : "test" } , { "message_id" : 4 , "sender_id" : 1 , "recipent_id" : 3 , "message" : "testting" }  ]

Comment: what is your query if there's timestamp column.please

Answer (score 0):

select * from tbl_messages1 where sender_id = 1 and message_id in
(select max(message_id) from tbl_messages1 group by recipent_id);

this is the anwer i was looking for.Here sender_id may be whatever I put.

Comment: You'd better delete this question. This does not help anyone in the future.